# Docusign Embedded Signing using template

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I need steps/procedure for  recipient  to sign via nodejs application using template.Currently i am  using the docusign node sdk.I would like to embed the signing into the application  (Embedded Signing) through the API rather than opening DocuSign in another window.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the DocuSign Recipes: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes.  The Recipes include node.js code samples for "send a signing request with a template (via email)" and also for "signing from within your app" -- between these two examples, you should be able to get code to accomplish your objective.  If you're unable to get it working using those examples, then post your code here for feedback.  (You're more likely to get help here if you post code and say "this is what I've tried..." than if you just expect someone to provide you the complete solution.)

Comment: Hi @KimBrandl -- Thank you for commenting on the question. Please provide your responses as "Answers" whenever practical. That way others can upvote your great answers, and it improves the statistics for the questions since right now the question doesn't have an "answer." Many thanks, Larry

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @LarryK -- will do. I'm always torn as to whether feedback like that above (which doesn't really answer the question, but rather, tells the poster where they might find the answer) is best suited for a Comment or Answer.  That said -- your points about SO statistics is certainly valid.  I've added my feedback as answer below.

Comment: Hi @KimBrandl, I know what you mean re "Answer." In these situations, my thought is that we're giving a "Helpful Response" instead of an "Answer." But sometimes that's most appropriate thing to be done given the OP. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you take a look at the [DocuSign Recipes](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes). The Recipes include node.js code samples for "***send a signing request with a template (via email)***" and also for "***signing from within your app***" -- between these two examples, you should be able to get code to accomplish your objective. If you're unable to get it working using those examples, then edit your post above to include your code and ask for feedback. (You're more likely to get help here on SO if you post your code and say "*this is what I've tried...*" than if you just expect someone to provide you the complete solution.)

Comment: Thanks @Kim Brandl ,